# Do not send registration mail to fake users, who haven't specified their gender in registration form

Tags: emails, advertising, users

Since several years I run [a Drupal 7 web site](http://preferans.de/user/register) - as a frontend to a multi-player card game.

I have the following SPAM protection at my web site: the new users should specify their gender at the registration (it should be "Male" or "Female", but not the default "Robot") and then they have to play the card game:

[image: screenshot]

Every night I run a cronjob, which deletes users who have wrong gender or who have registered 10 days ago and still haven't played:

```
delete from drupal_users
where uid <> 0 and
to_timestamp(created) < (now() - interval '10 day') and
uid not in (select distinct id from pref_money); /* haven't played the game */
```

This does work well, BUT recently the amount of registering fake users has increased to hundreds per hour and my site keeps sending lots of registering mails (which bounce then to my poor mailbox) every minute.

**So my question is:** how NOT to send the registration mail to users who have their gender set to "Robot"?

Here is what I have found sofar:

1) The gender (an additional field at my reg. form) can be found the following way:

```
        $result = db_query('select field_gender_value from {field_data_field_gender} where entity_id=:id', array(':id' => array($viewer_id)));
        $gender = $result->fetchField();
        if ('Robot' == $gender) {
           ....
        }
```

2) And I probably should provide a `hook_mail_alter` in my custom module:

```
function MY_CUSTOM_MODULE_mail_alter(&$message) {
  # XXX how to find gender here?
  if ('Robot' == $gender) {
      # XXX how to abort mailing for registration only?
      $message['send'] = FALSE;
      return;
  }
}
```

But in 2) I don't know 2 things - how to find the gender value there and how to cancel the registration mails only?

Any suggestions please?

*Please do not suggest the Mollom module or any standard Drupal anti-spam measures, because my question is very specific.*

Comment: mail_alter only has access to the message. Is the gender information part of it?

Comment: No and that is my problem - how to find the gender (an additional field in registration form) from the `hook_mail_alter`?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Does `$message` contain a reference to the related user account?

Comment: I don't know, that is why I am asking the Drupal experts here :-)

Comment: Ah ok - it would be _much_ easier (and quicker) for you to check that yourself than wait for someone here to set up a test and do it. If you don't already have it, install the Devel module, and add `dpm($message);` to the mail alter hook. Then invoke the email you're trying to catch into sending, and a message will appear on screen containing all the contents of `$message`

Comment: Do you mean I should add the following to my custom module? (I do have one to generate custom blocks): `function MY_CUSTOM_MODULE_mail_alter(&$message) { dpm($message); }`

Comment: Even if that were to be the case, scrapping the text for this information and then starting to dig in the DB would be terribly brittle. I don't think this is the way to go.

Comment: Yes something just like that. @Letharion I meant is there a _real_ reference to the account, not something in text (a uid in a parameter perhaps). That could be used to reliably load the user and get field info without being brittle. But I don't know if the params are passed on with the message after it's gone through `hook_mail()`

Comment: @Clive, I see. I started down the path of parsing out "Robot" form the text, before I realized how bad that would be, and then I interpreted your comment along the lines of that.

Comment: Assuming that if someone refused to specify gender equals being fake is pretty much pointless. Bots probably will specify it, they are written to specify everything and usually have some decent defaults and decent field recognition built in. On the other hand many real people thinks that specifying gender is a bad idea as they want to be judged by their words, not by their perineum. They might choose "robot" in good faith expecting it to be an option for people that don't care to be treated as either male or female.

Comment: Not at my website where I have it this way since over 2 years

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you implement [hook_form_id_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to either add a new validation function to the registration form, or replace the submit callback.

In a validation function, you have access to the form values, and you can do whatever checks you want, and fail the submission. This will reject the form all together.

If you replace the submit callback instead, you could override only the sending of the e-mail. but otherwise let the form pass through, which seems closer to what is being asked for.

Comment: Do you suggest to modify `modules/user/user.module`? Which method there? I'd like to change `user_validate_mail` - but how to find the gender field value there?

Comment: This is the best approach, but I would add an additional validation handler instead of replacing the submit function.

Comment: Additional validation handler does sound better, I'll update with that.

Comment: Idea is nice, but rejecting the form for bot will tell him he failed. So it's good idea to not highlight the field that failed. With CAPTCHA it's OK as it is supposedly unsolvable anyway, but here it would just tell bot to select another option and try again. Of course only smarter bots will ever try, but their number is growing.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that as well, which is why I ended up keeping the submit option in there as well. Overriding the submit one can still fake a successful POST.

Comment: The CAPTCHA Drupal module isn't stopping bots anymore - neither the Image, nor the Math. My Drupal 7.24 site had been under attack in recent 2 months by a bot, which uses us.er.n.a.me@gmail.com addresses and CAPTCHA (on password and user reg. forms) didn't stop it - until I installed a custom font + switched to russian letters.

Comment: How do you "fail a submission" in a `hook_form_id_alter` method?

Comment: You don't. If you read my answer above, I state however that you can do so in a validation function.